# Count all items from timespan list into one timespan

Tags: c#, timespan

Is there a way to count all the timespans from a list into one timespan.

Like:

`List(00:15:00 + 00:15:00) = TimeSpan(00:30:00)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Linq [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var timespans = new List<TimeSpan>
{
    new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0),
    new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)
};

var totalTimespan = timespans.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Add(y));
```